# Xcode Error: Cannot Parse the Debug Map : No such file or directory in iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting this error when I add some code I wrote with Xcode 7 targeting iOS 7 into an upgraded version of the code that now targets iO9

```
GenerateDSYMFile /Users/tobiomotayo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-crjhqevvqymedmbshmkkppicqbqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxx.app.dSYM /Users/tobiomotayo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-crjhqevvqymedmbshmkkppicqbqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxx.app/xxxx
cd /Users/tobiomotayo/Documents/Projects/xxxx-ios
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/tobiomotayo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-crjhqevvqymedmbshmkkppicqbqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxx.app/xxxx -o /Users/tobiomotayo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-crjhqevvqymedmbshmkkppicqbqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxx.app.dSYM

error: cannot parse the debug map for "/Users/tobiomotayo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-crjhqevvqymedmbshmkkppicqbqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxx.app/xxxx": No such file or directory
```

I have done Clean build, and I've deleted the Derived data and it still shows once I merge the files from the old source code.
I've checked if I have duplicate files. I've not found any. Though there are some that source control has hidden, so I had to rename the files so that there are not duplicates but then I still get the errors. 
Now I delete the content of the view controllers and it still shows, then it doesn't show when I delete the import lines at the top of the files.

Comment: error says there is no such file directory at mentioned path.

Comment: so what does that mean? could it be because some files I'm trying to import are not available yet?

Comment: Yes the file you are looking for is not present on that path.

Comment: But it doesn't show this error on a normal day when I try to import a class that doesn't exist.